# The € sign results in large PDF filesize (+70kb)

Tags: pdf, ms-word, pdf-generation

When exporting a PDF file from Word (2010 compatible), the simple EURO € sign adds ~70kb of filesize.

From **4kb** to **74kb** for an almost empty file: "test" versus "test €".

With 100k+ invoice files this is significant.
What could be a solution?

Comment: This is not a programming question. Try asking this in an end-user venue, such as Super User.

Comment: Likely the font used and it must be embedded. What font did you use for that symbol.

Comment: @KevinBrown It's simply Arial, which should support the euro sign.

Comment: Arial has a fairly large footprint. Do you know if the font embedding is subsetted?

Comment: @KevinBrown at 4kb, I assume the PDF has a subset of the Arial font for "test". On my mac, Arial.ttf is 773kb. Perhaps indeed the "subsetter" in the conversion tool flips on the € sign ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the € sign is an "unsafe" character, resulting in the embedding of the entire Arial font (while normally the PDF writer will assume Arial is available at the client computer).

Solutions:

- The suggested solution is to write "euro".
- Force to **not** embed the font, with the risk that the € sign is not/badly displayed (if your PDF creator allows)
- Embed a subset of the font (if your PDF creator allows)
- Use or create a font with smaller size (fewer letters/signs) and embed this font

https://www.aivosto.com/articles/pdf-optimize.html